# Excel formula to call data from separate sheet based on dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, import

I have data containing hours per week spent on projects for multiple projects being imported into a main excel sheet.

The weekly hours are used in a main summary sheet (Sheet A) that shows the hours spent per week on each project with the first data values being the current week (so 12/06/2023 at time of posting this).

[Photo 1- Sample of the data being pulled for 4 projects with the top row being days, noting that K3:K6 has info on the first week specific to that project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1SlL.png)

My issue is that Project 1 and Project 4 have largely different start dates.

[Photo 2- Summary Sheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHCw3.png)

Since the projects have different start dates, I cannot use an HLOOKUP to call the data in. From photo 1, this data is contained in Sheet B if all the projects had the same start date, I would replace the top row with the dates and effectively use the HLOOKUP there. I've tried using the index & match method and general nested IF statements but had no success.

Ideally in my summary sheet, I want Project 4 to output zero until 04/09/2023 in the summary sheet where it will begin pulling data from 'Sheet B'!K6:KX as seen in Photo 2.

What's the best way for me to approach this?

Thank you for reading this and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a hard time following - but trying to explain such things in words without having a back and forth conversation is hard.

Index Match is a bit defunct now that XLookup exists. Have a look and see if it meets you needs. There's also a chance that this is one of those rare circumstances that exact match is not wanted. Non-exact match finds the closest without going over, price is right rules. It's very good for ensuring you stay under budget, but in your case, the date component "may" work.

Xlookup
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929
As it's an array formula it can lookup "all" values in your date column and put them across when it finds its match.

XMatch with example of 2 dimensional array
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312

I'm guessing that the first sheet is "Project Week/Day" So the headers of 0,7 etc. are "week 1" "week 2". I would look at the cells being offset to their overall position in the year/timeline. But that does make it unweildy.

To clarify, you're looking at taking the numbers in picture 1, and putting them in the yellow section of picture 2, when the date matches? Picture 2 has a line for each project?

Comment: Thanks for your response and advice Inkca. I wish I could explain it more clearly but it's just as you said. I'll have a look at those two functions now!

Comment: How did you go?